# Using a function within list.files function in r

Tags: r

I want to create a program where I select files with a user defined prefix in `list.files()`

My folder will have files beginning with various characters. I want to define a variable or function at the beginning of the program which I can use in list.files in the program
List of file

```
MP201901   MP201902  MP201903  SG201901  SG201902  SG201903 XY201901  XY202001  XY202002
```

If I use

```
inpfiles1 <- list.files(path =Input, pattern = "*SG.*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

it gives correct output but I want to store the prefix somewhere so we can just change the prefix

Currently using code

```
A<-"SG"
inpfiles2 <- list.files(path =Input, pattern = "*A*.*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
but this is giving empty result
```

Comment: Save it as `A <- "my_pattern_here"` and pass simply `pattern=A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate the user-inputted pattern in `A` with your own suffix. I.e.

```
A <- "SG"
pattern <- paste0(A, ".*.csv")
inpfiles2 <- list.files(path=Input, pattern=pattern, full.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, R doesn't know that `A` is a variable name, and so it's ignoring your variable and literally using the letter A.

You can use paste0 instead:

```
A <- "SG" 
pattern <- paste0(A, '.*.csv')
```